# Exception when add Silverlight dll in WPF application

Tags: wpf, silverlight

When i added the silverlight dll in the wpf application , i got the following exception.

Could not load file or assembly "System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0". The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the
assembly reference.

This is happening only in VS 2010 professional Beta 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Silverlight directly in a WPF application, as they do not use the same version of the .NET Framework, thus the error message

Could you give some more details on your scenario ?
If you have a WPF app, you have more than what Silverlight can give to you.

If you are building a solution with multiple products, and one is WPF for the desktop, one is Silverlight for the Web, you need to create 2 different projects in VS.

Comment: Hi ,

I am creating designer support (VisualStudio.Design) for Our Silverlight Control.

Since it is not possible to create the desinger project in Silverlight, so i am trying to create the WPF application for this.

It works fine in VS 2008 , but it through the above mentioned issue in VS 2010.

Comment: OK, I understand the scenario.
I guess you already had a look at http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/11/17/silverlight-design-time-extensibility.aspx. The Silverlight toolkit seems to do what you are trying to achieve, see http://www.ningzhang.org/2009/10/21/silverlight-design-time-toolkit-october-2009-release-update/ Maybe you'll find a 'real' answer in the source code.

Comment: Hi,

actully i need to display the our own desinger window while clicking the our context menu provider in the xaml for our control.

I did this for  wpf version of our control, it works fine,

but when I start porting this for our Silverlight control i got the above mentioned issue.

ie) I'm able to add context menu provider in silverlight design, ie) I'm able to port the Meta Data class.

but when i add UserControl(desinger window) from the wpf desinger project then i got the above mentioned issue.

I will upload the sample if you are unable to understand the scenario.

Comment: I am sorry, I have never worked on designer issues with Silverlight. I won't be able to help you in this case.

Comment: Hi Timores,  i used a separate WPFControlLibrary project to achieve this, Now it is working fine. Thanks for the link you provided. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source tree here:
http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/

Specifically, the Expression.Samples.Interactivity.Design branch.

This shows a few examples of how to put in property editors for use with Blend. I'm not sure if the same concept is transportable to the Cider design surface, but heck, Blend is nicer for pure XAML editing anyways. :)